# nsIUploadChannel - The connection was reset

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I try to save post data to local file. But if i do that, in browser i see

> The connection was reset
>             The connection to the server was reset while the page was
>   loading.   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try
>   again in a few
>       moments.   If you are unable to load any pages, check your
>   computer's network
>       connection.   If your computer or network is protected by a
>   firewall or proxy, make sure
>       that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

There is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window id="yourwindow" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

 <script>
<![CDATA[
var MIKI =
{
 observe: function(subject, topic, data) 
 {
  if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") 
  {
   var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
   if(httpChannel.requestMethod == "POST"){
   var uploadChannel = httpChannel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIUploadChannel);
   var uploadChannelStream = uploadChannel.uploadStream;
   uploadChannelStream.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream);                 
   uploadChannelStream.seek(0,0);                               
   var stream = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);
   stream.init(uploadChannelStream);
   var data = stream.read(stream.available());
   data = data.split(/\r\n\r\n/).slice(1).join('\r\n\r\n');
   var buffer = httpChannel.URI.spec + " " + data+ "\n";
   if(data != '') fos.write(buffer, buffer.length);
  }
 }
} 
};
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("Desk", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
file.append("http-request-log.txt");
var fos = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
fos.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x10, -1, 0); 
var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(MIKI, "http-on-modify-request", false);    
]]>
</script>
</window>
```

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reading the data out of the upload stream to write it to the file, you are probably leaving the stream pointer at the end (so when the request happens it looks like the POST body is empty). Try seeking back to the beginning of the stream once you are done reading out the data.